# readelf fails in qemu chroot when using absolute path

Tags: linux, chroot, elf

I'm trying to install java 8 SDK in a qemu emulated chrooted environment and I'm running up against the following error

```
readelf: Error: /proc/self/exe: Failed to read file's magic number
```

Readelf works when the path is not absolute. The following outputs the correct header.

```
cd / && readelf -h proc/self/exe
```

But the following does not

```
readelf -h /proc/self/exe
```

Any suggestions or continuing debugging tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ls -l proc/self/exe /proc/self/exe
```

and see if there is a difference.

Why would you even want to show the header of `readelf` inside the chroot?

Comment: The /proc/self/exe is linked to /bin/ls, why does readelf not follow this symlink, why does using the absolute path matter? As to that second question, it's called in the pre-configuring packages process when installing oracle-java8-installer. I'm guessing it's for getting system information?

Comment: It must be an issue with qemu emulated chrooted environment, in a normal chroot both work. Also the message doesn't say `No such file`. It seems open is successful, but read isn't. Try `strace readelf -h /proc/self/exe`

Comment: The output of strace says it all! `qemu: Unsupported syscall: 26`. Thank-you so much for your help!